# App crashes while downloading videos(mp4) in flutter using (http or dio) package

Tags: android, flutter, video, download, crash

The only thing which comes in the console after the crash is
**Lost connection to device.**

Comment: while downloading video with(http or dio)  app memory usage increases and it crashes.

Comment: I found this while seeing flutter performance memory usage.

Comment: instead of `bodyBytes` use `Stream` from `StreamedResponse`

Comment: @pskink you are saying this while using http?

Comment: I am currently using http.get();

Comment: you need https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseRequest/send.html